# Нужно ли двоеточие перед кавычками?

Tags: пунктуация

Задав одному из прохожих традиционный вопрос «Как доехать до городского центра», услышал в ответ «Маршруткой до SM Sebu».

Answer (score 2):

*Задав одному из прохожих традиционный вопрос: «Как доехать до городского центра?» - услышал в ответ: «Маршруткой до SM Sebu»*.

Если это прямая речь, то должен быть знак вопроса, а если есть вопросительный знак, то после прямой речи ставится тире.

Если нет вопросительного знака, следует оформить как косвенную речь:

*Задав одному из прохожих традиционный вопрос, как доехать до городского центра, услышал в ответ: «Маршруткой до SM Sebu»*.

Теперь насчёт двоеточия.

К правилам есть примечание:

> Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов
>   предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не
>   ставится: Это "не хочу" поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Г.);  Он
>   вспомнил пословицу "За двумя зайцами погонишься - ни одного не
>   поймаешь" и отказался от первоначального плана; С криком "Спасайте
>   детей!" юноша бросился в горящее здание.
>
> Но **если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова предложение,
>   выражение, надпись и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие:** Над
>   воротами возвысилась вывеска, изображающая дородного амура с
>   опрокинутым факелом в руке, с подписью: "Здесь продаются и обиваются
>   гробы простые и крашеные..." (П.); Мимо станции проносились скорые
>   поезда с табличками на вагонах: "Москва - Владивосток"…

http://www.testsoch.info/pryamaya-rech-vnutri-avtorskix-slov/

Слова **вопрос, ответ** входят в это "т. п.", они вводят прямую речь, двоеточие ставится.

Comment: Людмила, очень смущает отсутствие должного обособления деепричастного оборота. Тире не может "съесть" запятую, поскольку они ставятся по разным мотивам. Да и вообще, в нацкорпусе встречается самое разное оформление подобных конструкций вообше без тире.  ***Лев Александрович Аннинский настороженно и высоко сказал “да?”, но, услышав, о ком речь, спросив “как их здоровье и жизнь?”, сразу пригласил меня на обед в Союз писателей.*** (Лев Зайчик, журнал "Звезда). Не великий авторитет, конечно, но всё-таки.

Comment: То есть в нашем случае такой подход предполагает и первую "прямую речь" рассматривать как "элемент предложения", не требующий, ни двоеточия, ни тире. Почему-то мне такая пунктуация понятнее и ближе.

Answer (score 1):

Задав одному из прохожих традиционный вопрос: «Как доехать до городского центра», услышал в ответ: «Маршруткой до SM Sebu».

Прямая речь в конце предложения определённо, в первом случае — немного иной подход: прямая речь естественным образом встраивается в структуру предложения (оборота), и после неё нет тире.

> Пробормотав: «Барчуки проклятые», он закурил сигару и плотнее
>   завернулся в шинель.

Comment: Пробормотав привычную фразу "Барчуки проклятые", он закурил сигарету и плотнее завернулся в шинель. Заметна разница? Спросив одного из прохожих: «Как доехать до городского центра»... и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

***Задав одному из прохожих традиционный вопрос: «Как доехать до городского центра?», - услышал в ответ: «Маршруткой до SM Sebu».***

Запятая после кавычек обязательна уже потому, что она закрывает деепричастный оборот. Я (уже после реплики под ответом Людмилы) нашел еще несколько тому подтверждений.

Вот максимально близкий случай.

> Поэтому Николай Иванович, глупо спросив: «Что?..», — сел на постели, а
>   нежный призрак, оказавшись рядом, задул свечу и сказал уже нормальным,
>   даже умоляющим голосом:...

(Борис Васильев).

Остальное больших сложностей не должно вызвать.

Ну а мой вариант с кавычками, но без прямой речи в первом случае (*Задав одному из прохожих традиционный вопрос «Как доехать до городского центра?», услышал в ответ: «Маршруткой до SM Sebu»*) я не буду навязывать в силу его дискуссионности. Хотя мне он нравится.