# Нужна ли запятая после прямой речи?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, прямая-речь, деепричастный-оборот

Нужно ли ставить в данном предложении запятую или тире?

> Парень громко хмыкнул, как бы спрашивая: "Чего уставилась? Ещё
>   хочешь?"(,) и отвернулся.

Comment: Подобный вопрос уже [обсуждался ранее](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/452459/183462).

Answer (score 4):

1. Нужна **запятая**, закрывающая деепричастный оборот.

> Если прямая речь находится внутри слов автора, то перед ней ставится двоеточие, а после нее — или запятая, или тире, или запятая и тире (**по условиям контекста**):
>
> *…Софья Карловна ещё раз поцеловала Маню и, сказав ей: «Поди, гуляй, моя крошка», сама поплелась за свои ширмы* (Леск.) — запятая закрывает деепричастный оборот, в состав которого включена прямая речь.

См. [**Прямая речь внутри слов автора**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159) (Справочник Розенталя).

Пример из Национального корпуса русского языка:

*Поэтому Николай Иванович, глупо спросив: «Что?..», сел на постели, а нежный призрак, оказавшись рядом, задул свечу и сказал уже нормальным, даже умоляющим голосом:* [Борис Васильев. Дом, который построил Дед (1990-2000)]

2. В правилах также отмечается, что если прямая речь заканчивается вопросительным знаком, восклицательным знаком или многоточием, то после неё ставится **тире**:

> *На вопрос мой: «Жив ли старый смотритель?» — никто не мог дать мне удовлетворительного ответа* (П.)

Поэтому считаю, что в данном случае нужны **оба знака**, каждый из которых ставится на своих основаниях. Такой вариант не противоречит информации из справочников (Розенталь, Лопатин), уместен и грамматически, и графически, и интонационно:

***Парень громко хмыкнул, как бы спрашивая: «Чего уставилась? Ещё хочешь?», — и отвернулся.***

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108635/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Answer (score 2):

*В этом предложении ставится тире: Парень громко хмыкнул, как бы спрашивая: **"Чего уставилась? Ещё хочешь?" —** и отвернулся.*

Постановка тире, а не запятой связана **с вопросительным знаком**.

Если бы прямая речь была повествовательной, то тогда ставилась бы запятая.

ПАС: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138

Сравнить: а) запятая ставится, если она была необходима **в месте разрыва вводящих слов автора**: Сказав: «До скорой встречи», она быстро вышла из комнаты;

в) тире ставится, если прямая речь заканчивается **многоточием, вопросительным или восклицательным знаком**.

Answer (score 2):

**Парень громко хмыкнул, как бы спрашивая: «Чего уставилась? Ещё хочешь?» — и отвернулся.**

Постановка тире, а не запятой обусловлена [§ 136, *в*](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138) из справочника Лопатина:

> в) тире ставится, если прямая речь заканчивается многоточием, вопросительным или восклицательным знаком

Поднятый в комментариях вопрос о возможной необходимости как запятой, так и тире, при включении прямой речи в деепричастный оборот явным образом не освещается в справочнике, но я сошлюсь на похожую ситуацию, где исключается «третий лишний» знак препинания, — § 137, *г*:

> г) **запятая и тире** ставятся между репликами, принадлежащими разным лицам, но объединенными общим авторским предложением: *Когда приказчик говорил: «Хорошо бы, барин, то и то сделать», — «Да, недурно», — отвечал он обыкновенно* (Г.); **если же в первой реплике имеются знаки восклицательный или вопросительный, запятая опускается**: *Когда я спросила: «Почему вы носите на спине ковер?» — «Мне холодно», — ответил он*; то же при ином расположении частей авторского предложения: *Когда я спросила: «Почему вы носите на спине ковер?» — он ответил: «Мне холодно»* (Ток.).

P. S. Здесь, кстати, не сказано про многоточие, но кажется, что оно не должно в этом отношении отличаться от вопросительного или восклицательного знака.

**Обновлено**

Пример именно деепричастного оборота со знаком препинания в конце прямой речи есть у М. Булгакова:

> *Но признаться в этом он не пожелал и, воскликнув укоризненно: «Ах,
>   развратница!..» — тут же зачем-то очутился на кухне.* («Мастер и Маргарита»)

Хотя здесь сочетание восклицательного знака и многоточия, а не просто вопросительный знак, как в предложении вопроса.

Другой пример есть в [коллекции цифровых образовательных ресурсов](http://school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore-wrapper/1946d260-e1a1-4308-8126-72b39aaea09a/punc25.htm):

> Воскликнув: «Ты лентяй!» — отец схватился за ремень.

Comment: Спорный вопрос состоял в том, что в ПАС и у Розенталя нет ПРИМЕРОВ именно с деепричастным оборотом. У вас есть такие примеры или разъяснения из других источников относительно именно таких конструкций? Иначе мне кажется, что в вашем ответе нет новой информации. Вот у Александра приведен пример из Нацкорпуса, где ставится запятая, а не тире. Это ошибка?

Comment: @Sharon добавил подходящий пример. Запятую *вместо* тире я бы ошибкой не считал, но запятая *вместе* с тире после знака препинания в прямой речи — явный перебор

Comment: @Sharon Самое интересное, что в найденном мной источнике совсем другая пунктуация (нежели дает Нацкорпус). _Поэтому Николай Иванович, глупо **спросив: «Что?..», — сел** на постели, а нежный призрак..._ Я считаю, что должно быть или тире (с двоеточием), или запятая (без двоеточия).

Comment: @Sharon Вот ссылка: https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=153043&p=40

Comment: Мне не нравится этот вариант, вряд ли он соответствует правилам. Это можно записать так: (1) Поэтому Николай Иванович, глупо спросив: «Что?..»,  сел на постели... (2).Поэтому Николай Иванович, глупо спросив: «Что?..» — сел на постели...

Comment: @Smylic Спасибо за ваши примеры. Я думала, что вы новый участник, а вы просто редко сюда заходите.  Хотелось бы чаще видеть ваши ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ дан с учетом проведенного **обсуждения темы.**

1. Примера с деепричастным оборотом, в состав которого входит восклицательная или вопросительная прямая речь, **в ПАС или у Розенталя нет.** Поэтому решить задачу можно, **исходя из общих правил**: если на месте разрыва слов автора  была запятая, а прямая речь содержит вопрос или восклицание, то после нее ставится **не запятая, а тире.**
2. У нас есть **все основания предполагать, что это касается любых конструкций**, в том числе и деепричастного оборота. Интонационно это можно объяснить тем, что  без паузы, обозначаемой тире, сложно выразить вопросительную или восклицательную интонацию.
3. **Безусловной ошибкой было бы употребление одновременно двух знаков** (запятой и тире). В правиле Розенталя **тире и запятая** употребляются для разделения **реплик двух разных персонажей** в одном предложении.

... Когда приказчик говорил: «Хорошо бы, барин, то и то сделать», — «Да, недурно», — отвечал он обыкновенно. (Г.); **запятая и тире разделяют две реплики** разных лиц, находящиеся внутри слов автора. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159

4. Примеры из литературы, приведенные ниже, кажутся **образцовым оформлением** подобных конструкций.

*Он только указал мне рукой на детей, **сказав: "А вот и потроха мои!"―** и затем насильственно усадил меня на диван.* [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Святочный рассказ (1858)]

*Гость робко представился поэту, тот плеснул в стакан какой ― то горючей смеси **и, сказав: "Ваше здоровье!"―** хлопнул содержимое, не предложив, однако, гостю выпить.* [Виктор Астафьев. Затеси (1999) // «Новый Мир», 2000]

5. В текстах **можно встретить** использование запятой, а не тире, учитывая сложность темы и отсутствие примера в правилах. В то же время такой вариант можно допустить **при  оформлении коротких реплик**, когда и двоеточие можно ставить не всегда.

Comment: Ни в коем случае не хочу ставить под сомнение правильность постановки только тире и примеры из литературы. Но есть замечания. **1**. В пункте 1) у вас написано: _если на месте разрыва слов автора была запятая, а прямая речь содержит вопрос или восклицание, то после нее ставится не запятая, а тире._ Нет такой формулировки в правилах (смотрим ваш первый ответ). **2**. В  пункте 3) говорится о совершенно другом правиле, которое не исключает возможность двойного знака в иных случаях, поэтому о _безусловной ошибке_ нельзя так категорично говорить. **3**. В ответе два пункта 3).

Comment: Юпитер, ты сердишься — значит, ты не прав. Ваши замечания не кажутся мне справедливыми. Я привожу общую формулировку правила, разве она не верна?  В правилах У Розенталя и Лопатина разве есть примеры с двойным знаком? А пункт № 3 вы могли бы поправить сами в качестве редактора.  Из всего вышеизложенного следует, что мой ответ  совершенно правилен и вам бы надо за него проголосовать, а то кто еще проголосует! (Шутка).

Comment: Да не сержусь я. Уже кажется, что эта тема не слишком-то и значительна. А по поводу формулировки: вы же вывели свою, что тоже не плохо. И ещё непонятно, что значит, _без тире сложно выразить вопросительную интонацию_? Разве знака вопроса недостаточно?

Comment: Я проголосовал за другой ваш ответ :) Хотел за "Много людей", а оказалось, что там уже стоит моя стрелка.

Comment: Спасибо, спасибо!  А я пока думала о значительном. Представляете, вокруг ни одного знака, Оказалось, что эти слова никак не связаны (по словарю проверяла).  Может, вообще не стоит здесь проводить время (среди незначительного)?  А про интонацию сложно объяснить в двух словах. Что-то вроде того.  Если мы ставим запятую, то прямая речь теряет самостоятельность и произносится в одну фразу со словами автора (я это называю встроенной интонацией). А если тире ставим, то  всё произносится, как обычно (пауза после двоеточия, собственная интонация с вопросом и т.д.). Прямая речь выделена, подчеркнута.

Answer (score 1):

Поучаствовал в обсуждениях, подумал. Моя версия: нужна и запятая, и тире.

Запятая ставится по общему правилу выделения деепричастного оборота (как и любого другого). Без разницы, что включено внутрь него. Есть строгое правило: если с одного знака началось, то тем же знаком и закрывается. Мне попались исключения в справочнике. В них вторая запятая замещалась интонационным тире. Но! Это было только в случае, когда имелись сразу два условия: 1) деепричастие короткое, в два-пять слов; 2) деепричастие обязательно стоит в начале предложения. В нашем примере деепричастие сложное и стоит в середине предложения. Так что говорить о том, что один знак "съедает" другой, нет смысла. Я вообще критически всегда отношусь к такому подходу: удалить важный для пунктуации знак только из соображения "облегчить" предложение. Каждый знак стоит по своим основаниям. Один не может взять на себя функцию другого, а тем более сразу двух.

Тире ставится для того, чтобы обозначить, что завершена та часть предложения, которая открывалась двоеточием. Убрать или опустить тире нельзя. § 136.ПАС  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138 требует постановки тире, если прямая речь имела вопросительный знак. Его нельзя заменить его запятой. Если вы убираете из предложения тире, то должны убрать и двоеточие. Речь в кавычках тогда станет дополнением.

Здесь писали, что запятая и тире ставятся вместе между репликами, принадлежащими разным лицам, но объединенными общим авторским предложением. Да! Но вы упустили из виду то, что в правиле не сказано **ТОЛЬКО В ЭТОМ СЛУЧАЕ**. Это лишь один пример, когда такое сочетание знаков возможно. Например, запятая и тире вместе могут возобновлять части сложного предложения.

Приведу пример для этого случая:

> Разумно ли прийти к заключению, что в период времени, когда наука стояла так высоко, когда человеческие силы, по сравнению с нашими в нынешнее время, были изумительны, — что в такое время эти несокрушимые творения, в которые трудно поверить, — такие достижения, как у египтян — были посвящены заблуждению <...>

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте § 136.ПАС http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138 Там всего три пункта по нашей теме (а, б, в).  Там написано о постановке запятой ИЛИ тире очень четко и однозначно. В п.а приведен пример с деепричастием и поставлена запятая. Примера с деепричастием и тире, к сожалению,  нет. О запятой и тире не сказано ни слова. Что же еще нужно учитывать, куда же яснее?  Зачем приводить информацию, не относящуюся к теме, и нарушать правило.

Comment: Или другой вариант.  Приведите хотя бы один пример из художественной классики, где есть деепричастие и вопросительная прямая речь и где поставлен двойной знак. Одно такое предложение будет выглядеть намного убедительнее, чем длинный текст.

Comment: @Sharon спасибо, я принял к сведению ваше мнение. Дополнил ответ вашей ссылкой. Противоречий в своём ответе не вижу. Про нарушение правила ничего не понял. Ну да ладно. Не буду перегружать комментарий. Скажу только про классику: во-первых, совсем нет желания искать такой пример, я просто высказал свои соображения; а во-вторых, я сомневаюсь, что он там будет. Тенденцию закрывать все обороты, даже стоящие перед тире, я наблюдаю в современных произведениях. За Толстых и Пушкина даже в нынешних изданиях я ручаться не стану.

Answer (score 1):

1. После прямой речи ставится тире, так как она заканчивается вопросительным знаком.
   Парень громко хмыкнул, как бы спрашивая: "Чего уставилась? Ещё хочешь?" — и отвернулся.
   Запятая, "закрывающая деепричастный оборот", **не нужна**.

У Лопатина:
*Петр Михайлыч хотел сказать: «Не впутывайся ты, пожалуйста, не в свои дела!» — но промолчал* (Чехов).
Без прямой речи, то есть на месте разрыва авторских слов, перед союзом «но» необходима запятая. (Петр Михайлыч хотел сказать, **но** промолчал.) А ее нет.

У Розенталя:
*И только когда он шептал: «Мама! Мама!» — ему становилось как будто легче* (Чехов).
Тут запятая необходима между частями сложного предложения. (И только когда он шептал, ему становилось как будто легче.) И здесь ее нет.
Чем же деепричастный оборот лучше?

Деепричастный оборот **перед** прямой речью (М. Булгаков) — без запятой после кавычек, только тире:

> Однако постепенно он успокоился, обмахнулся платком и, **произнеся довольно бодро**: «Ну-с, итак...» **—** повел речь, прерванную питьем абрикосовой.

Деепричастный оборот **после** прямой речи (Л. Толстой) — если придерживаться "правила открытия" деепричастных оборотов и следовать вашей логике, то после кавычек тоже должна быть запятая. Она отсутствует:

> Она, выйдя из двери, остановилась в коридоре и, разводя толстыми, короткими руками, все повторяла: «Что ж это будет? Сделайте милость! Что ж это?» **— обращаясь к своему адвокату.**

2. Предложения такого типа очень часто оформляются без выделения прямой речи и без постановки вопросительного знака, потому что выражение "как бы спрашивая" эту вопросительную интонацию уже подразумевает.

*Медленно, спокойно, как бы спрашивая, кто мы и что нам надо, беркут наклонил голову и сложил крылья* ([Б. Емельянов. Слепой беркут](https://www.kuncevo-online.ru/kniga_rasskazi_o_gaidare.php) [Рассказы о Гайдаре]).
*Когда Рия подошла ближе, он вскочил и внимательно заглянул ей в глаза, как бы спрашивая, прошло ли все гладко или попало по первое число* (Ю. Прерия).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, за ваше мнение, которое я считаю правильным. Мне кажется, что нам не мешало бы добавить вариант оформления без двоеточия, но с запятой. "Парень громко хмыкнул, как бы спрашивая «Чего уставилась? Ещё хочешь?», и отвернулся. Здесь прямая речь является дополнением.